# Splitting a string into various bits

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string which looks like this:

substring = 'Xmole(1)=0.0Xmole(2)=1.0rho(1)=2343rho(2)=2343'

I need to split this into :

```
                              Xmole(1)=0.0
                              Xmole(2)=1.0
                              rho(1)=2343
                              rho(2)=2343
```

Is there an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Where did the string come from oriniginally?It would be a lot easier if it was delimited somehow. Can you alter how that string is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your numbers are always in the format of your example, that is, digits and possibly a decimal point (and not for example in the form "1.0e-3"):

```
ind = regexp(substring,'=[\d\.]+', 'end');
result = mat2cell(substring, 1, [ind(1) diff(ind)]).';
```

The variable `result` is a cell array with one string in each cell:

```
result = 

    'Xmole(1)=0.0'
    'Xmole(2)=1.0'
    'rho(1)=2343'
    'rho(2)=2343'
```